# Flask - ImportError: No module named migrate.versioning

Tags: python, flask, importerror, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm working through a flask tutorial and am trying to run a script that creates a database instead of doing it through the command line. It uses the SQLAlchemy-migrate package, but when I try to run the script, it gives an ImportError.

This is the terminal output:

```
Sean:app seanpatterson$ python ./db_create.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./db_create.py", line 2, in <module>
    from migrate.versioning import api
ImportError: No module named migrate.versioning
```

This is the db_create.py script:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,     api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

This is the config file it references:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

This application is being run with a virtual environment. This are the module that relates to it that I have installed in the environment:

sqlalchemy_migrate-0.7.2-py2.7.egg-info

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ImportError: No module named migrate.versioning` probably means the module is not installed. Make sure it has been installed in the correct virtual environment, it is activated (you ran the `activate` script in that environment) and the selected Python binary is actually making use of that environment (i.e. you are using Python2 and not Python3).

Comment: Yes you're totally right, I did have the module installed in the virtual environment all along. Doh!

Answer (score 22):

```
pip install sqlalchemy==0.7.9
```

and

```
pip install sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2
```

and

optionally this flask-whooshalchemy==0.55a should solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

As said by @BoppreH earlier

```
ImportError: No module named migrate.versioning
```

means that the module named 'migrate' is not installed in your virtual environment or your system. First make sure that you are using the proper environment and that it is activated using the **activate** script.

I had the same problem and had the correct environment set up. But still the error was not solved.

What worked for me was installing the **sqlalchemy-migrate** package from pip. After *activating* my environment, I ran the following code to install it :

```
pip install sqlalchemy-migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

`flask/bin/pip install flask-sqlalchemy` without defining the version worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

run :

```
   easy_install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

to install Flask-SQLAlchemy

```
   sudo pip install flask-migrate
```

to install flask-migrate

Answer (score 0):

I think this error might pop up for several obscure reasons, I would like to add another which I experienced:
I had the same exact error while having sqlalchemy-migrate correctly installed, and guess what, it didn't work just because I had **named** the migration script file as `migrate.py`, this created some conflict with the migrate package. 
In fact PyCharm warned me with this message: 
*`"Import resolves to its containing file... This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't."`*

I **renamed** the migration script as `db_migrate.py` and everything started working fine. 
I could understand what was the issue cause I had another project with an identical set-up but with migrate-sqlalchemy working perfectly and the only difference was indeed that file name...
Hope this might help someone one day...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - "No module named migrate.versioning", and everything is much easier than we are talking about, you need to perform the commands "run" 
file: db_create.py or file: db_migrate.py if you using PyCharm (not from the terminal). And you will have the expected output: "New migration saved as D:...there is my path...\microblog\db_repositort/versions/001_migration.py
Current database version: 1"

Comment: Hi ALexandr, if you can format your answer, so the commands to run, the filenames  and the expected output, can be easily differentiated from the text.